# JavaScript: Append to the top of .CSV

Tags: javascript, csv

I run below SHell script to create .CSV log.

```
cd /Volumes/Hams\ Hall\ Workspace/Mannequin_1_WIP && echo "Mq1:,"`ls |grep \_01.tif$ | wc -l` ", , Images:,"`ls | wc -l`  >> ~/Desktop/RT3.csv
```

Then Javascript to add an extra column

```
logfile_name = "~/Desktop/"
var f = new Folder(folderName + logfile_name);

    if ( ! f.exists ) {
        f.create();

        var fileOut = new File(f+"/"+'RT3.csv');
        if (!fileOut.exists) {
          fileOut.open("w");
          fileOut.writeln(",", docRef.name);

          fileOut.close();
        }

    } else {

        var fileOut = new File(f+"/"+'RT3.csv');   
            fileOut.open("a+");
            fileOut.writeln(",", docRef.name);

            fileOut.close();
    }
```

And then again run Shell, to create 3rd Column.

At the moment the final .csv comes out something like this. It creates new column, but starts from the end. How would you make it start at the top?

[image]

But would love to create something more uniform like so:

[image]

Comment: So read before you write

Comment: pun intended? :D Although, Could you please elaborate? When I read before writing, instead of outputting at the very end it now outputs 1 line before the end.

Comment: Read the line, concat, read concat

Answer (score 0):

Create object array.
While reading the file append the new record or line to the array.

Then write out the array.